# VIM: Repeating t and T movements

Tags: vim, motion

The `;` movement is supposed to repeat `t`, `T`, `f`, and `F` movements. For `f` and `F` this works fine as the cursor is placed *on* the character. However, pressing `;` after `t` or `T` does not work as VIM finds the same character again and again (i.e., the cursor will not continue to move).

Is there a workaround for this? Might it be considered a VIM bug even though technically it is correct?

Comment: The workaround is to do `2;` I'm not sure this behavior can be considered a bug, though, but it should be more carefully documented.

Comment: you should definitely have a look at easymotion plugin - it changed my ouse of f,F,t,T completely https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I recall this was a bug that has now been fixed.

It seems fixed in vim version 7.3.584

What version of vim are you using?

Bill

Comment: Thank you, I'm still on 7.3.154. It is great to know that this is fixed! How did you find that? I cannot find the VIM bugtracker.

Comment: There isn't a bug tracker, but you can find descriptions of patches in ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.3/README. It looks like it was fixed at 7.3.235: '";" gets stuck on a "t" command, it's not useful'.

Comment: Thanks. I did find that page but I cannot get past the first 200 bytes or so, the page hangs.

Comment: That link was ftp, try this http link:

http://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.3/README

Answer (score 5):

That behavior is controlled by the `;` flag of 'cpoptions'. Execute

```
:verbose set cpo?
```

to see how yours are set.

This is a `vi`-compatibility issue. If your `Vim` is configured to be `vi`-compatible, the `;` will be included in 'cpoptions' and you will get the behavior you observe. See

```
:help 'cpoptions'
:help cpo-;
:help 'compatible'
```

The solution to your problem depends on how you got `Vim` into this vi-compatible state. One usually has to go to extra effort to do that, such as starting `Vim` as "vim -u NONE", with `-C` or with no .vimrc file in your home directory.

**Edit:**

This was a problem that was fixed in Vim 7.3.235 with the addition of the `;` flag to 'cpoptions'. In earlier versions, `Vim` always behaves as described in dotancohen's question.

Comment: I don't see a mention of `;` in `:h 'cpoptions'` or `:h 'compatible'` and `:set cpo?` returns `aABceFs`. None of these letters seem to be related to `tTfF` or `;,`.

Comment: It's at the bottom of the list of flags under ":help 'cpoptions'". See ":help cpo-;". I'll add that to my answer. The value of 'cpo' that you are seeing is the default when `Vim` is started in 'nocompatible' mode, which is the usual case. See the very first line of ":help 'cpoptions'". If you start `Vim` in vi mode (i.e., 'compatible'), for example by staring it as "vim -u NONE", then 'cpo' will contain all the option flags including `;` and you will get the vi-compatible behavior of `;`.

Comment: Well, my Vim version is 7.3.35 and I don't see `;` at all in the help. Furthermore, Vim spits an `E539` when I do `:set cpo+=;` whether I'm in compatible mode or not. This is probably a version problem.